# Is there a symbol used to say "is well ordered by?"

Tags: notation

For example, we know that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered by $<$. Is there a standard way of representing this using some notation?

Comment: I don't recall any special notation in any of the materials on the subject I have seen. If there is any, it's likely not widely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is common to denote any partial order by symbols like $<$, $\leq$ or $\prec$ or $\preccurlyeq$. None of these are used exclusively to denote total orders, though.

Also, it is good practice to use words rather than symbols when explaining something. Symbols and notation are only useful in order to make formulas intelligible - too much notation hinder understanding.